# Combining QUERY and IMPORTRANGE with today's date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

### Requirement

I need to import data from an external Google Sheet, where there is a date/time column, and values are populated as `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, e.g.:

```
29/06/2023 13:34:19
```

[image]

**Note**: This data is entered using **[AppSheet](https://about.appsheet.com/home/)** app so i cannot change or add extra columns to change the data as it will impact the appsheet.

### The Problem

I only want to extract data which has **today's** date. So I tried using the query:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","ONLINE ORDER RECONCILIATION!a:M"), 
   "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col12,Col13 where Col13 is not null and Col13 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' "))
```

Unfortunately the result doesn't bring in any data. I **think** it is because the datetime in `Col13` is not in a format that `QUERY` is able to understand:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
> Invalid date literal [2023-06-29 00:00:00]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd

[image: [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0FKq.png]]]

Answer (score 0):

You may try with FILTER and CHOOSECOLS instead of QUERY:

```
=LET(importedrange,IMPORTRANGE("URL","ONLINE ORDER RECONCILIATION!a:M"),
CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(importedrange,DATEVALUE(INDEX(importedrange,,13))=TODAY()),1,2,12,13))
```

---

OPTION 2:

Assuming you actually have dates in that column (working with dates can be tricky...), you can adapt your QUERY in order to be equal or higher to today, and lower than tomorrow:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","ONLINE ORDER RECONCILIATION!a:M"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col12,Col13 where Col13 is not null and Col13 >= date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&" and Col13 < date '"&text(today()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: hello Martin.
it didn't work. i am getting the following error:
Error
Function CHOOSECOLS parameter 3 value is 2. Valid values are between -1 and 1 inclusive.

i entered the URL correctly. unfortunately i couldn't troubleshoot it as i am not very familiar with these formulas.

Comment: I can't troubleshoot it either without any data, but try option number 2!

Comment: Hello martin, apologies for the delay. attaching a test Google sheet where i have mocked up data for you. will be great if you can have a quick look:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ywU-XumQWjBIX_XWuv5ZTkEQe5yVe7h3IJ6NSNmJKZA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello! I just added an extra simple quotation mark after the first date and it worked!: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ywU-XumQWjBIX_XWuv5ZTkEQe5yVe7h3IJ6NSNmJKZA/edit#gid=1211355482","SOURCE!a:M"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col12,Col13 where Col13 is not null and Col13 >= date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col13 < date '"&text(today()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")